# Deploy crystal report to server

Tags: asp.net, deployment, crystal-reports, assemblies

Hi I need to deploy my asp.net project with crystal report to my server. 
I try downloading the file from http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_3.exe.

But now I facing the error when install the file
**"You must already have VS 2010 installed to proceed with this installation"**

What doest this means? It means I should install visual studio to my deploy server ?

Here is the error I faced when run my asp.net project

```
    arser Error Message: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

All assemblies related to **crystaldecision** throw the errors above. Anyone have a solution?I am using window server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to install the developer version of cyrstal report, instead you just need the runtime version on server.

[Download link](http://service.sap.com/sap/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm)

You can also find the download link under *Where can I find the required runtimes?* on [this page](http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/06/28/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010--deployment).

Comment: Hi , i cant access your link. File no found. please send me again